# Nested many to many form using cocoon Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, apache-cocoon

I'm trying to make it possible to add multiple `crops` to a `spray_program` through `program_crops` in a nested form using cocoon. I'm able to add one but the link_to_add_association button just adds # to the url. Ill add the bits of code I think will be relevant let me know if there is something else...

```
nested form in spray_program form
<div id="programCrops">
     <%= form.fields_for :program_crops do |program_crop_form| %>
      <%= render 'program_crop_fields', f: program_crop_form%>
    <% end %>
    </div>
    <div class="links">
      <%= link_to_add_association "Add crop", form, :program_crops %>
    </div>
```

_program_crop_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.collection_select :crop_id, Crop.all, :id, :name %>
    </div>
    <%= link_to_remove_association "Remove crop", f %>
</div>
```

I suspect building the model only once here may be the issue and this needs to be passed elsewhere

```
 def new
    @spray_program = SprayProgram.new
    @spray_program.build_program_sprayer
    @spray_program.program_crops.build

  end
```

the model

```
class ProgramCrop < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :crop
  belongs_to :spray_program inverse_of: :program_crops

  validates :spray_program, uniqueness: { scope: :crop }
end
```

No JavaScript errors being thrown in console. The dropdown renders correctly and creates one many to many association as expected. Sorry if I've missed something important it's getting late!

--Additional models

````
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :farm
  has_one :user, through: :farm, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :program_doses, dependent: :destroy
end
```ruby
class SprayProgram < ApplicationRecord

  has_one :program_sprayer, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :program_crops, inverse_of: :spray_program, dependent: :destroy
 

  has_one :sprayer, through: :program_sprayer
  has_many :crops, through: :program_crops


  accepts_nested_attributes_for :program_sprayer
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :program_crops, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

  # validates_associated :program_sprayer
end
````

params produced look like this

```
    {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]",
     "spray_program"=>
      {"date(1i)"=>"2022",
       "date(2i)"=>"8",
       "date(3i)"=>"1",
       "farm_id"=>"1",
       "program_sprayer_attributes"=>{"sprayer_id"=>"1", "litres_per_min"=>"4", "speed"=>"7"},
       "program_crops_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"crop_id"=>"8", "_destroy"=>"false"}}},
     "commit"=>"Create Spray program"}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses, I wasn't using `inverse_of` anywhere but had `accept_nested_attributes_for`, I've played around with both a but don't seem to be able to get it working. One `program_crop` is attached successfully despite the fact the params seem to be invalid if i use them to create a spray_program in the console. I'll add the other relevant models

Answer (score 0):

without the other model I can't answer for sure, but I suspect that you are missing either `accepter_nested_attributes_for` or `inverse_of`, check the note under Basic Usage in here, https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/cocoon/1.2.12

> Rails 5 Note: since rails 5 a belongs_to relation is by default required. While this absolutely makes sense, this also means associations have to be declared more explicitly. When saving nested items, theoretically the parent is not yet saved on validation, so rails needs help to know the link between relations. There are two ways: either declare the belongs_to as optional: false, but the cleanest way is to specify the inverse_of: on the has_many. That is why we write : has_many :tasks, inverse_of: :project

This basically allows to have a reference to an object on the new action, without having that objects id(because it hasn't been created yet), by building the object you are giving the data to the form, but the form doesn't know how to link them, so you end up sending back to the backend two objects that don't reference each other

Comment: Thanks for the explanation it makes a bit more sense to me now but not sure I'm implementing it correctly. Ive added the other models now, and the params being put out. I did have `accept _nested_attributes` set, have tried adding `inverse_of` a couple of ways. But situation is the same, not able to generate more forms, the single one works though

Answer (score 0):

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Please review this, you need to tell the modal that you are accepting nested attributes, cocoon works this way, if you still not finding the solution, please share other modal too

Comment: Thanks, I've added the other models as I still can't get it working. Wondering if it might be to do with my class/I'd setup being wrong as the `link_to_add_attribute` button href is always set to #

Comment: @JamesReed Please make sure, you done this 
'yarn add @nathanvda/cocoon'

also the following is written in your app/javascripts/packs/application.js if Rails 6
require("jquery")
require("@nathanvda/cocoon")

If not rails 6, you can check here according to your version https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

Please confirm that you want cocoon for spray programs has many program crops?

and please try '@spray_program.program_crops.build' instead of '@spray_program.build_program_sprayer'

Please share your feedback I would be happy to help

Answer (score 0):

I got it working eventually, I tried testing whether jquery was being loaded and it wasn't, cocoon didn't. I think something was wrong in my webpacker settings, after running `rake assets:clobber` I hit a webpack missing entry error so followed [this guide](https://dev.to/dani8439/rails-6-webpacker-manifest-missingentryerror-4fi7) after which my local server worked again.

At this point I noticed there was an error locating the cocoon module in application js after webpack compiled for my local server (I messed up the install or import somehow).

In the end i used [this vanilla js version](https://github.com/oddcamp/cocoon-vanilla-js) of coccoon following the instructions and it's playing nice now.